# Add a control parameter in line of code when connection is opened with external database

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to retrieve information from an external database by opening an ODBC connection. I use the following line of code.

```
 Sub executequery(query As String, arrRecords As Variant, totalrecords As Integer)
    Const adOpenStatic = 3
    Const adLockOptimistic = 3
    Const adUseClient = 3
    Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set objRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    objConnection.Open "DSN=AR System ODBC Data Source;"
    objRecordset.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    objRecordset.Open query, objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
    arrRecords = objRecordset.GetRows
    totalrecords = objRecordset.RecordCount
    objRecordset.Close
    objConnection.Close

    End With
End Sub
```

In this code objRecordset.Open query, objconnection, adOpenStatis, adLockOptimistic line in the code retrieves the data. I have multiple test cases. For the cases where data is present in the database it gives back the value. For the cases where no data is present in the database it gives an error. Instead of the error in my code, i want it to jump to the end i.e. to close the connection and return where it was initially called. I know this is complex. Please let me know if more information with screenshots is required.

Comment: You might want to take a look [here](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ErrorHandling.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub executequery(query As String, arrRecords As Variant, totalrecords As Integer)
On Error GoTo Get_Out
Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adUseClient = 3
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objConnection.Open "DSN=AR System ODBC Data Source;"
objRecordset.CursorLocation = adUseClient
objRecordset.Open query, objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
arrRecords = objRecordset.GetRows
totalrecords = objRecordset.RecordCount
objRecordset.Close
objConnection.Close

End With
Get_Out:
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Man! thanks a lot, it works like a charm. It would be really appreciated if you could help me with the another problem i am having. I am using this code which says that if arrRecords which is the string that holds the data retrieved from the database is empty skip the print array step and if it is not empty Print Array. When i execute it, i get a type mismatch error. This is the code i am using -

Comment: If arrRecords = "" Then
GoTo Get_Out
   
Else
PrintArray arrRecords, Y, Lastrecord, 1

End If

Get_Out:

Comment: Great that it works :) You should edit your question to fit in this follow-up question with the correct formatting. Right now it's pretty hard to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hey no it does not work, can you please tell me how i can paste the whole code here for you to rectify?

Comment: I meant great that the part I've already answered worked. Regarding your further questions, you have to edit your question to incorporate the relevant code and any questions you want answered.